# Trouble connecting Cinema Display to desktop PC with mdp graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, mini-displayport

I just bought a used graphics card (Radeon HD 6870) because it has mini displayports for the sole purpose of connecting to my Apple Cinema Display (LED version).

I've tried inserting the mdp that comes out of the ACD into the graphics card and nothing happens. At all.

The graphics card itself works just fine when I use the DVI to my dell.

I'm not sure if it's the ACD not being compatible or the ports being inactive/dead. I'm not sure how to test for the latter since I don't have any other mdp devices.

In some obscure forum post I found a user who claimed updating the vBIOS was what helped him because the mdp ports weren't working otherwise. The flashing software claimed the BIOS currently on card were the same as the one I was trying to load.

I'm really stumped. I want to clear up my desk and just use my ACD alone.

UPDATE: I am a complete moron. I was plugging it in upside down. I have no idea how it went in I thought it was only way. It began working perfectly after plugging it in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may find it useful to read this link through

http://ryanuber.com/11-23-2011/running-27-in-apple-led-standard-pc.html

Your solution would be by upgrading the PC's motherboard Bios or changing the Motherboard.

i got to your question here by following the Upwork freelance task post by the way ..

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I upgraded my motherboard BIOS to 2013 version from 2010. Unfortunately still same issue. This guy seems to have replaced his entire motherboard, a bit overkill and expensive for my taste. Though his card in the original motherboard wouldn't function at all, while mine functions on DVI just fine (I'm using it right now!). Cool the task is still open